# Append array and a scalar value to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, append

I am trying to a append a numpy array and a scalar value to a numpy array.

```
logf= np.array([20, 25, 31.5, 40, 50, 63, 80, 100, 125, 160])
logf = np.append(logf, [[logf*10], [logf*100]])
logf = np.append(logf, 20000)
```

In order to append a scalar value I am appending it using a second append function. I want to know if it's possible to append an array and a scalar value using a single append function.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected result here?

Comment: array([   20. ,    25. ,    31.5,    40. ,    50. ,    63. ,    80. ,
         100. ,   125. ,   160. ,   200. ,   250. ,   315. ,   400. ,
         500. ,   630. ,   800. ,  1000. ,  1250. ,  1600. ,  2000. ,
        2500. ,  3150. ,  4000. ,  5000. ,  6300. ,  8000. , 10000. ,
       12500. , 16000. , 20000. ])

Comment: That is not what _append_ does. You actually want to _extend_ the array. With numpy, you can do it using [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

Comment: `np.append` is a poorly conceived cover for `np.concatenate` - it takes 2 arrays while `concatenate` takes a whole list.  Read its docs, and then forget about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for `.concatenate()`:

```
import numpy as np

logf = np.array([20, 25, 31.5, 40, 50, 63, 80, 100, 125, 160])
logf = np.concatenate((logf, logf * 10, logf * 100, [20000]))
print(logf)
```

Result:

```
[   20.     25.     31.5    40.     50.     63.     80.    100.    125.
   160.    200.    250.    315.    400.    500.    630.    800.   1000.
  1250.   1600.   2000.   2500.   3150.   4000.   5000.   6300.   8000.
 10000.  12500.  16000.  20000. ]
```

`numpy.concatenate()` expects a series of input arrays of equal dimensions, so you can't just pass in the scalar value like `20000` - instead you can just wrap it in brackets to have it be a one-dimensional array like the rest of the expressions. Also note that `logf * 100` is an expression that results in a one dimensional array already, so no need for extra brackets there.